# d3.js : dynamically passing data to pie chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

In my AngularJS App, I have used flot chart to plot dynamic values in a pie chart as in this link below :

http://plnkr.co/edit/WEJMA0f7DnnAh6h8jaMW?p=preview

In flot chart, I can pass the pie chart values at runtime with  tag's 'chartdata' attribute and scope variables.

```
div ng-repeat="user in recordedEvents"  ng-style="{'display': 'inline-block' }">
    {{user.name}}
    <div class="flotcontainer" my-chart chartdata="user.data"></div>
</div>
```

Am trying to similarly pass dynamic data in D3.JS. Here is an example I tried:
http://plnkr.co/edit/iQfkXewUVAylVU4s2913?p=preview

But am not sure how to pass dynamic data here in D3. It doesn't seem to have any tag similar to the  tag's 'chartdata' tag.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is create reusable directives that encapsulate the D3 functionality I'm trying to use. So whenever I want to use, say, a pie chart, I simply use my custom pie chart directive:

```
<my-pie-chart chart-data="val"></my-pie-chart>
```

The directive code handles all the D3 drawing for me. [Here's](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/5372077) someone else's example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: am not getting how to use this for pie chart. the example you gave is for a bar chart. can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use a full set of premade directives.

I found [Angular-NVD3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) to be quite good, but the [Angular-NVD3-Directives](http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives) are more popular.
Angular-NVD3 defines its charts properties as a JavaScript object, in the controller :

```
{
  "chart": {
    "type": "pieChart",
    "height": 500,
    "showLabels": true,
    "transitionDuration": 500,
    "labelThreshold": 0.01,
    "legend": {
      "margin": {
        "top": 5,
        "right": 35,
        "bottom": 5,
        "left": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Angular-NVD3-Directives defines its charts properties in HTML code :

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <nvd3-pie-chart
    data="exampleData"
    id="exampleId"
    width="550"
    height="350"
    x="xFunction()"
    y="yFunction()"
    showLabels="true">
    <svg></svg>
  </nvd3-pie-chart>
</div>
```

You'll find detailed examples on both pages.

Comment: I want to use just d3. nvd3 wouldn't suit my case because it doesn't seem to have support for mobile. Any alternative suggestion please?

Comment: @Jean You'll have to create a custom directive. But having used both of these, I can guarantee you Angular-NVD3 is fully responsive. Just try resizing the browser on the [pie chart example](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/pieChart).